# Update Static JSON file from Django page

Tags: python, json, django, django-staticfiles

I'm building an app at work for part number creation/management with Django. I current use a json file to inform/enforce some of the part number rules on the part number creation page. I'd like to be able to update this json file from the web page so that when we need to edit or add to the current part number schemes the person doing so doesn't need a technical background. To do this I want to send a json object to the view and use it to update/replace the original json file.

I've tried to access it using the static url

```
static('/javascript/json_file_name.json')
```

I've also tried to access it using its file path.

both have not been successful.

This is a tool used inside a private network hosted on a raspberry pi and won't be public.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can treat your object as model rather than static file.
FileField is usefull for your purpose https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#filefield.

Here is the related code in the documentation:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/uploads
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/')
    # or...
    # file will be saved to MEDIA_ROOT/uploads/2015/01/30
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d/')
```

This way you can write a view to serve and manipulate your object.